# Fastest key/value pair container in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I am creating a syntax highlighting engine. My need is very specific. Keywords will be associated to their respective attribute array via a pointer. The data structure will look something like:

```
dict = {
    "printf": keyword_attr_ptr
  , "sprintf": keyword_attr_ptr
  , "#import": special_attr_ptr
  , "string": lib_attr_ptr
}
```

The look-up needs to be very fast as I will be iterating over this list every keypress.

I'm asking this question because I can not find any good documentation regarding how NSDictionary caches (if it does) and looks up values by its keys (does it use a map? a hashmap?). Can I rely on NSDictionary to be optimized to search for keys by strings?

When I was doing something similar a long while ago I used the MFC CMap function with very good results. NSDictionary *appears* to be the equivalent to CMap but the key type isn't specified and the NSDictionary clearly states that a key can be any type of object. I just want to make sure I can rely on it to return the results extremely fast before I put a lot of energy into this problem.

**UPDATE 1**

After a day of research, I ask the question on SO and I find the answer immediately after... go figure.

This is the documentation related to Dictionaries:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html

It uses a hash table to manage its storage. I guess the short answer is that its almost equivalent to CMap.

Comment: You might also want to look at [Foundation Data Types](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) (`NSMapTable`) and [Core Foundation Types](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CoreFoundation_Collection/_index.html) (`CFDictionary`).

Comment: NSDictionary, CFDictionary, and NSMapTable are all essentially the same implementation, these days, just different APIs.

Comment: @Kurt: I suggested those because it's possible that skipping the message passing of `NSDictionary` will be helpful, but of course only testing will tell for sure.

Comment: Just saw that too, lulius. The only difference I see is that NSMapTable holds a weak reference to its value. I'm guessing that's the only difference. I guess now I just want to feel warm and fuzzy that this is the right API for the job. It appears that it is.

Comment: It's not closely related, but something you should understand about Cocoa data structures is that their naming is actually misleading. For example, `NSArray` and `CFArray` are not arrays (so they are not `O(n)`)! They are actually `O(log n)` at the worst case, and usually `O(n) regardless of their size. Check http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html out. <---- It's a terrific article, and you don't want to miss it (it has nice graphs too).

Comment: @PooriaAzimi I prefer to think of it as that their naming is entirely correct but per sound object-oriented principles the name doesn't disclose the implementation. An `NSArray` holds an ordered sequence of objects, which is how I'd define an array, an `NSDictionary` holds a mapping of keys to values, which is how I'd define a dictionary, etc, etc.